# Sum IIF with multiple values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sum, iif, ssrs-expression

I am having an issue with my expression.

I am trying to write: if it finds these specific codes in the Dataset column, Sum them and return the amount. However, I am receiving `#ERROR`.

Any help with this expression is really appreciated.

```
=Sum(IIf(Sum(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "EPOC, EPTX, STOR, PARK, ANTR", (Fields!Amount.Value), "$0.00"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an expression like this:

```
=SUM(IIF(UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "EPOC" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "EPTX" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "STOR" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "PARK" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "ANTR"
        , Fields!Amount.Value
        , 0 ))
```

OR If the BillCode value has other information besides the code then something like this

```
=SUM(IIF(UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "*EPOC*" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "*EPTX*" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "*STOR*" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "*PARK*" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) LIKE "*ANTR*"
        , Fields!Amount.Value
        , 0 ))
```

**To format** it to show as currency either set your textbox format to `C0`

OR Set the Expression `=Format(SUM.....,"C0")`

OR Right Click and go to textbox properties and set the format

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I believe my issue was that I had not separated each value exclusively in the expression.

Comment: Note there is one Parenth missing at the end. Should be:

=SUM(IIF(UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "EPOC" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "EPTX" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "STOR" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "PARK" 
         OR UCASE(Fields!BillCode.Value) = "ANTR"
        , Fields!Amount.Value
        , 0 ))

Answer (score 0):

Try expression like this

```
=Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!BillCode.Value, "EPOC") > 0
             OR InStr(Fields!CODE.Value, "EPTX") > 0
             OR InStr(Fields!CODE.Value, "STOR") > 0
             OR InStr(Fields!CODE.Value, "PARK") > 0
             OR InStr(Fields!CODE.Value, "ANTR") > 0,
         Fields!Amount.Value, 0))
```